# installing electrical boxes for out door light fixtures

Tags: lighting

want to install light fixtures on each side of my garage door if I use weather proof boxes should any type of light fixture fit over them?

Comment: You need to provide more details. Is this a decorative light like a sconce or or flood light?

Answer (score 4):

If you are wanting to install a wall sconce, you need to install one that is rated for outdoor use.

**Note:** The shape box you need to use will be dependent on what fixtures you would like to install. Some fixtures need round boxes while others require a rectangular box. My examples show round boxes, but this is not the only choice.

Aside from being constructed for outdoor (ab)use, outdoor rated fixtures typically include a foam/rubber gasket, a specially designed fixture base, or some other means for ensuring water resistance. Additionally, in many cases, you should use silicone caulk around any possible points of water incursion (if possible).

[image]

---

Some fixture bases come with extra holes for mounting flood lights. These extra holes should be plugged and then caulked around the seams.
*Note the fixtures are installed in the side holes, and the hole in the middle that has been plugged.*

[image]

---

It is also good practice to use wire nuts that contain silicone sealant, known as *weatherproof wire nuts* among other names, or to wrap normal wire nuts in electrical tape. This provides an extra layer of moisture defense for your electrical connections.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thumbs up for mentioning the waterproof wire nuts.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The smallest diameter recessed box to my knowledge is 3.5. Exposed "non recessed" boxes are definitely an odd choice for hanging decorative sconces. I also cannot stand sealing wall lights with silicon, nor do I recommend using those silly direct burial wire nuts.

Comment: Odd choice for one person might be the OP's only practical option, however he did not specify what _type_ of fixture he wanted to install, so it's open to interpretation. The silicone suggestion comes straight from most manufacturer's directions for metal exposed boxes (for the boxes, not the lights). Any reason why you don't recommend those "silly wire nuts"? At this point I'm assuming my answer got a down vote for suggesting additional weatherproofing deemed unnecessary.

Comment: Never have I seen silicon recommend by the manufacture for sealing an outdoor light. I think your recommending direct burial wire nuts for a non buried connection is overkill and bad advice. Never in the trade is this practiced.

Comment: Never in the trade, or never in the trade in your area? I'm not from a school of thought that says overkill is bad advice, especially for something as trivial as a wire nut. Can it hurt? I guess it can make a silicone mess. Can it help? Potentially. I have seen mfg instructions explicitly state to seal knockout plugs with silicone caulk to maintain the wet location rating for the box. You can argue any caulk past that is overkill.

Comment: Ideal WeatherProof Wire Connector: _Suited for interior and exterior electrical connections exposed to rain or damp conditions_

Answer (score -1):

Many RAB outdoor LED fixtures can benefit by filling the gooseneck, esp if upside down, (Manf. requirement in that case.) Most problem free installs use a round box, recessed, with the gaskets or other suitable method to shed water and limit air infiltration.